# Uploaded to iTunesConnect as v2.2.14 but Submitted as v2.2

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, version-numbering

My iOS app uses `CFBundleShortVersionString` to check the user's current version of the app.

When I uploaded my app to iTunesConnect, the version number in Xcode and in TestFlight was 2.2.14 , but when I selected that build for submission to the App Store in iTunesConnect I assigned it as v2.2

What version number will `CFBundleShortVersionString` return when the app is live in the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's shows same the version number you enter on iTunesConnect.

The same problem is faced earlier,But it shows the iTunesConnect version number.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I have actually found this to be incorrect. I assigned the `Version` in Xcode to be 2.10.1 and assigned the `Version Number` in iTunesConnect to be 2.10 - when this went live in the App Store, the App Store says it is version 2.10 but the `CFBundleShortVersionString` value displayed in the app says 2.10.1, which matches the Xcode value.